# SpagoBI - multivalue parameter

Tags: parameters, reporting, business-intelligence, spagobi

I'm using SpagoBI for some week now, and I have some issues to configure parameter.

I would like to have a multi-value parameter on a String column... I tried with: `$P{par_columne (";,;")}` like in the documentation.
But that didn't work and I have an error when I try with my dataset on my cockpit...
It's look like if the queries be: `Select ... From ... Where column in (""String"')`.

Here my error message :

> Impossible to load dataset [testParamWithQuery] due to the following
>   service errors: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near ''"Etat inconnu"' GROUP BY s.name' at line 5;

I tried a lot a prefix and suffix, but I didn't succeed

Do you have a idea about how to process or what I could did wrong?